# bash: print a dynamic variable using dynamic name

Tags: bash

In a for, I have the following:

```
COUNT="1"  
GEOZONE[1]="EU"  
declare -A CLIENTS_"${GEOZONE[$COUNT]}"="client1 client2"
```

At this point, if I would like to print *${CLIENTS_EU}* it works, but how to print that by using the *GEOZONE* array?

I got bad substitution while trying to:

```
~ $ echo ${CLIENTS_${GEOZONE[$COUNT]}}
bash: ${CLIENTS_${GEOZONE[$COUNT]}}: bad substitution
```

And I got *EU* while trying to:

```
~ $ echo $CLIENTS_${GEOZONE[$COUNT]}
EU
```

I would like to get *client1 client2*

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a separate variable that will hold composite variable name:

```
# ccomposte variable name
var=CLIENTS_"${GEOZONE[$COUNT]}"

# assign value
declare $var="client1 client2"

# print it
echo "${!var}"
```

```
client1 client2
```